# SQL - Get stored procedure multiple record sets to temp table variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get stored procedure multiple result set to temp table variable?

I wrote a stored procedure like,

```
Create proc test1
(
 @param1 int,
 @param2 int
)
as
Begin
     Select Id, Name from Table1 where column1=@param1;
     Select Id, Age, Address from Table2 where column1=@param2;
End
```

When i execute this sp it will return 2 tables(record set's).

Now, i want to get this 2 record sets to 2 temp table variables.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a stored procedure can return multiple result sets like you want it to. What I might suggest is to have the stored proc store the results in two global temp tables and then have the calling process (whatever is calling your stored proc) query the two global temp tables and put the results into your temp table variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and maybe I am misunderstanding what you want, but if you just want to take those two recordsets and put them into temp tables, couldn't you do this:

```
Create proc test1
(
 @param1 int,
 @param2 int
)
as
Begin
     Select Id, Name 
          into #temp1
          from Table1 where column1=@param1;
     Select Id, Age, Address 
          into #temp2
          from Table2 where column1=@param2;
End
```

now, I dont know what you're trying to achieve with this, but depending on how you're calling that sp, the #temp tables may not be accessible from outside of the sp.